# How to manage versioned objects constructors?

Tags: java, json, gson

We are currently working on a project using `java` where we expose REST API.
As we are working on OO language and export content in `json` format,
we searched for a library to support conversion of objects to `json` with versioning support.

We decided to use `gson`, as it offers an easy annotations for versioning.

The problem we are facing is a breaking in the API where some field (let's say plate) is removed and another one is added (say driver) and they are of the same type.
How can we build the constructors in this situtation, where the signatures are the same?

The solution I came up with is as follows:

Car:

```
...
@Since(1)
@Until(2)
private String plate;
@Since(2)
private String driver;

// v1
public Car(String plate){
  this(plate, null);
}

// v2
public Car(String plate, String driver){
  this.plate = plate;
  this.driver = driver;
}
...
```

And for creating the v2 `Car`, where I need just the driver field, I will execute it as follows:

```
Car car = new Car(null, driver);
```

I am not a fan of passing null (especially in the ctors), is there a better more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Did you consider using a factory? I think the factory pattern fits your requirements.

Comment: I would have said builder but yes, this is a design concern. Extraction construction from the class would be, imho, the best solution.

Comment: It is very hard to maintain your solution. Maybe it's better to have a separate Car class like CarV1, CarV2 for each version, use them in REST api and do field copying

Comment: I think that @IQV 's solution based on factories is a good choice here. IMHO, builders may be good as well, but builders are weak at compile-time for correct instantiating the target type instance until the runtime. Another solution is just hiding the public constructors (which is almost always good), and creating static factory methods like `carV1(plate)` and `carV2(driver)` that would just delegate arguments to the proper constructor parameters. With static factory methods you also can apply some semantics by giving the methods meaningful names therefore encapsulating what's under the hood.

Comment: I think managing different object versions is the worst solution since I will have loads of code duplication. In this way I just need to write the appropriate constructors. I will try to use here a factory I think...

Comment: However, I think that this question is highly primarily opinion-based since you've already been given 4 different approaches in four comments above. :)